# Couldn't cover one line test method

Tags: unit-test

I have the test which when I submit to force.com security scanner. I couldn't cover `public static id acid {get;set;}` which is in 8th line, and got this output from the security scanner:

> "Path 1: Query Name - Test_Methods_With_No_Assert Severity - Information 8. public static Id acid get;set;} //test_axtria_call_plan_pc.cls"

How can I fix this?

```
@isTest
public class Test_Call_PC
{
    private static Account objAcc;
    private static user objuser;
    private static user objuser1;
    private static List<Account> objAccount ;
    public static id acid {get;set;}

    public static testmethod void Axtriatestmy()
    {
         LoadData();
         CreateAccount();

         // snip - other code has no bearing so removed for clarity
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a member variable of a test class it doesn't need covering so you can ignore it. On other classes you'd get coverage by doing `Class.Member = xx;`.

As an aside, I noticed your tests didn't make use of `System.Assert()`, you really should use this to test functionality of your methods etc., after all that's the purpose of tests, just executing the code isn't doing much!

**Update**

Now that I can see that your real error is missing assert statements in those getter and setter methods. The best option would be to just delete the `{get; set;}` from that line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just re-edited the code. Could you look at once. Problem is Iam getting such result after scannner                                                 "Path 1:
Query Name - Test_Methods_With_No_Assert
Severity - Information
8. public static Id acid get;set;} //test_axtria_call_plan_pc.cls"

Comment: I cut the code because most of it is redundant for the question — you should have posted the error though! :)

Comment: Ok.. thanks. I removed that get;set; and submitted to scanner. I will give an update on the result. thanks

Comment: Thanks LaceySnr♦. by removing get;set;                              I could able to pass in secuirty scanner. Thanks once again